# Please help save my Dracaena Compacta

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, indoors, hydroponic, dracaena

Is my *Dracaena compacta* dying? This is a Hydroculture plant. I’ve only had it for 1 month and it has started developing brown and yellow tips. Some leaves have gone brown and fallen off. I water it once a week or whenever the metre is at minimum level. I use filtered tap water. I also use Formulex every 3 watering. I occasionally mist the plant if it feels dry. The plant is kept in the corner of the room near the front window. The sun does not shine in my room but does get natural light. The TV next to the plant has lights behind it which are often on during the evenings. The temperature in my room is around 19 degrees. Not enough water or over watered? Not enough light?[image: Dracaena Compacta]

Answer (score 1):

Plant need light to make energy, If it doesnt have energy it will not be able to support all this growth and will start shedding the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Turning up heat in the room to about 22 degrees may help. I would recommend moving the plant to where there is sunshine so it grows better. I wouldn’t use filtered tap water since it does not include the minerals that are needed for your plant.

In conclusion, the main thing you should do is that the water you give to your plant is mineral water/ tap water. It may be good to give a little bit of fertilizer.